# Determine the order of consistency of $y_{n+1}=y_n+(h/2)(y_n'+y_{n+1}')+(h^2/12)(y_n''-y_{n+1}'')$ (I want to improve my answer)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I can solve this problem but I was wondering if there is a quicker way to do it since time will be tight during the exam... I would really appreciate your tips and advice on how to calculate this in a different way. Thanks a lot!

**QUESTION:** Consider the autonomous, scalar differential equation $y'=f(y)$ and the numerical method defined by
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2}(y_n'+y_{n+1}')+\frac{h^2}{12}(y_n''-y_{n+1}'').$$

Determine the order of consistency of the given method.

**MY ANSWER:**

Consider
$$r_n=y_{n+1}-y_n-\frac{h}{2}(y_n'+y_{n+1}')-\frac{h^2}{12}(y_n''-y_{n+1}'').$$
Taylor expanding, we have
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+hy_n'+\frac{h^2}{2}y_n''+\frac{h^3}{6}y_n'''+\frac{h^4}{24}y_n^{iv}+\frac{h^5}{120}y_n^{v}$$
$$y_{n+1}'=y_n'+hy_n''+\frac{h^2}{2}y_n'''+\frac{h^3}{6}y_n^{iv}+\frac{h^4}{24}y_n^{v}$$
$$y_{n+1}''=y_n''+hy_n'''+\frac{h^2}{2}y_n^{iv}+\frac{h^3}{6}y_n^{v}$$
Therefore,
$$r_n=\left[\frac{1}{120}h^5-\frac{h}{2}\frac{h^4}{24}-\frac{h^2}{12}\left(-\frac{h^3}{6}\right)\right]y_n^v=\frac{1}{720}h^5 y_n^v=\frac{1}{720}h^5 y_n^v$$
Therefore, the method has consistency of order 4 with error constant $\frac{1}{720}$ at order $h^5$.

**Is there a formula or a quicker method I can use to calculate the order of consistency without calculating the error constant?**

Comment: You may recognize the Euler-Maclaurin formula, it is known that
$$
\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} f(x) dx = \frac{h}{2}(f(x_n) + f(x_{n+1})) + \frac{h^2}{2} (f''(x_n) - f''(x_{n+1})) - \frac{h^4}{720} (f'''(x_n) - f'''(x_{n+1})) + o(h^5)
$$
and note that 
$$
f'''(x_n) - f'''(x_{n+1}) = -h f''''(\xi)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exponential as a test function. Set $t_n=0$, $t_{n+1}=h$, then the error term is
$$
e^h-1-\frac{h}2(e^h+1)+\frac{h^2}{12}(e^h-1)=e^h(1-h/2+h^2/12)-(1+h/2+h^2/12)
$$
where one may recognize the numerator and denominator of the [2,2]-[Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_table#An_example_.E2.80.93_the_exponential_function) of the exponential function,
$$
e^h=\frac{1+h/2+h^2/12}{1-h/2+h^2/12}+O(h^5)
$$